# Situation with Magento: mage_newsletter is disabled, but it still appears in website

Tags: php, magento

I disabled the mage_newsletter in Magento, but newsletter subscription still appears in checkout when a customer buys an item.

I have tried flushing the cache, but this makes no difference. Any ideas?

Comment: This question is better suited on [Magento Stack Exchange](http://magento.stackexchange.com/). SO is for programming questions only.

Comment: Okay, I'll post it on there. Thanks